# Why does my Django robots.txt works on development but returns server error 500 on production?

Tags: python, django, robots.txt

I'm trying to create a robots.txt file for my django website following [this tutorial](https://www.pythonsetup.com/how-add-robotstxt-file-django-application/)

The end result is good on development and everything is working. However, when I pushed the files into production I got a Server Error (500) even though I changed all the 127.0.0.1:8000 into mywebsite's domain.

My settings.py Installed apps looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'search.apps.SearchConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'robots',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]
```

My main project's urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("search.urls")),
    path("sitemap.xml", sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    path('robots.txt',include('robots.urls')),

]
```

I installed the django-robots using pip install, and I did the necessary migrations on my production server but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try doing: `sitemap.xml/` and `robots.txt/` (note the trailing backslash)

Comment: @JonPizza I tried this, and now both my sitemap and robots don't work even after getting back to previous settings.

Comment: Make sure that your production configuration not disallowed any path. And with me, I recommend to serve these files by web server when you deploy production. E.g: Nginx or Apache